# Best practice for Service Oriented Achitecture & recommended maximum line count

Tags: architecture, application-design

Hopefully this won't be a point of personal opinion but instead settle an argument a colleague and I are having about the design of the application.

We use a repository pattern for our data layer and services for applying business logic. A service could have one or, more likely, many repositories within it.  So lets give an example (I don't work for a school, but it's a simple example):

My Repositories could include:

```
SchoolRepository
ClassRepoistory
DepartmentRepository
TutorRepository
TutorDepartmentRepository
TutorSkillsRepository
StudentRepository
StudentClassRepository
```

So in my mind, I would have three services (my example is in c# but this would apply to any language):

```
public class SchoolService : ISchoolService
{
    public SchoolService(ISchoolRepository schoolRepository,
                         IClassRepository classRepository,
                         IDepartmentRepository departmentRepository)
    {
        ....
    }
}

public class TutorService : ITutorService
{
    public TutorService(ITutorRepository tutorRepository,
                        ITutorDepartmentRepository tutorDepartmentRepository)
    {
        ....
    }
}

public class StudentService : IStudentService
{
    public StudentService(IStudentRepository studentRepository,
                          IStudentClassRepository studentClassRepository)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Now, in my example the `TutorService` could potentially need data from the `DepartmentRepository` and the `StudentService` could also potentially need data from the `ClassRepository`.  My argument is, should you need a `Class` object from the `ClassRepository` it should be retrieved from the `SchoolService` and that object should be passed through as a parameter as shown below:

```
// School service created by DI framework
var class = schoolService.GetClassById(1);

// Student service created by DI framework
var student = studentService.GetStudentById(1);
var studentClasses = studentService.GetStudentClasses(student, class);
```

I have tagged another question onto my title of this post as well around the maximum sizes of classes.  I have suggested this should be no more than 500 lines (including curly braces {}, new lines to make it readable, etc) as this makes it more manageable.  Am I talking out of my backside or is there some sense in my thinking?

Answer (score -1):

You titled this post as a SOA question but your design is anything but. You have a tightly coupled application where each of the components has intimate knowledge of the others. In fact these are object with direct reference.

This isn't necessarily a bad thing since a monolith is a viable option for small systems but it isn't SOA. Though if I did design a system in the size mentioned above I'd probably try to simplify it since the "layering" here brings a lot of overhead and very little benefit (because of the tight coupling)

Comment: Hmmmmm, I was ever so slightly concerned that someone would go down this route - I was going to mention something about this in my post. I couldn't be bothered to mention making the objects loosely coupled, instead I wanted to focus on weather or not is a good idea to use multiple repositories over many services or ensure that a repository is only ever used within on service.  Does this make sense?

Comment: You seem to define a repository per table - If I'd be using repositories I'd have one per service which abstract the tables related to the service.I'd also keep each service so it would handle its own tables (and not have shared tables).

Comment: So, just to be clear, you would have a SchoolService handle SchoolRespository and ClassService handle ClassRepository, etc? Isn't that extreme if that is the case?

Comment: For this sample I'd probably have Faculty, Student and a School service - Assuming the tutor and student has some business logic besides being assigned to classes. Each would hold a repository that would handle the tables it. There's no point creating a lot of services if they don't bring something new. And for SOA to be effective services should communicate with messages not class dependencies (again, that isn't necessarily bad to build a monolith with lots of classes it is just not SOA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments but I don't think you covered everything in my question.  My question asked about using the same repository over multiple services - and also looking at typical line numbers for services as well.

Comment: As I told you using the same repository (i.e. tables) in different services is a sign your services are tightly coupled and not really services

Comment: I've updated my question to point out that my objects are not tightly coupled

Comment: Your object might not be tightly coupled but your services are  as they are sharing the same underlying tables and so a change in one will result in changes in the others